# Templated Using with Nested Template

Tags: c++, templates, type-alias

The following code does not work because the inferred template parameter F is `std::tuple`, whereas I want it to be `Foo` - the former takes two template parameters and the latter takes one.

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
using Foo = std::tuple<int, T>;

template <template <typename> class F>
void foo(F<std::string> bar) {}

void test() {
  foo(Foo<std::string>());
}
```

Is there any way to make type inference work with the `using` statement rather than turning `Foo` into it's own class?

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
class Foo {
  std::tuple<int, T> bar;
};

template <template <typename> class F>
void foo(F<std::string> bar) {}

void test() {
  foo(Foo<std::string>());
}
```

### More Info

I am using C++17's `std::variant` along with using to alias types that are generic on a single type and I would prefer to declare these with `using` statements rather than creating wrapper classes for each one. Something like this:

```
// Assuming Plus, Minus, etc all exist
template <typename T>
using Operation = std::variant<Plus<T>, Minus<T>, Times<T>>;
```

### Building a Haskell-Style Functor

The point of this exercise is to build a small functor library loosely based on Haskell's functor typeclass. I have defined the "typeclass" like this:

```
template <template <typename> class F>
class Functor {
public:
  template <typename T, typename U>
  static F<U> fmap(std::function<U(T)> f, F<T> functor);
};
```

But I also wanted to add some sugar so that you can create a general mapper that will map a function over any function type without pre-specifying the functor type:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct FMap {
  FMap(std::function<U(T)> f) : f_(f) {}

  template <template <typename> class F>
  F<U> operator()(F<T> functor) {
    return Functor<F>::fmap(f_, functor);
  }

private:
  std::function<U(T)> f_;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
FMap<T, U> fmap(std::function<U(T)> f) {
  return FMap<T, U>(f);
}
```

This works well with a simple value-wrapper functor:

```
template <typename T>
class Value {
public:
  Value(T value) : value_(value) {}

  const T& value() const {
    return value_;
  }

private:
  T value_;
};

template <>
template <typename T, typename U>
Value<U> Functor<Value>::fmap(std::function<U(T)> f, Value<T> value) {
  return Value<U>(f(value.value()));
}

void test() {
  std::function<std::string(int)> fn = [](int x) {
    return std::to_string(x);
  };
  auto result = fmap(fn)(Value(42));
  // result.value() == "42"
}
```

Now I am trying to get it to work with a more complicated type that uses `std::tuple` or `std::variant` like in the above example.

```
template <>
template <typename T, typename U>
Foo<U> Functor<Foo>::fmap(std::function<U(T)> f, Foo<T> value) {
  return Foo<U>(std::get<0>(value), f(std::get<1>(value)));
}

void test() {
  std::function<std::string(int)> fn = [](int x) {
    return std::to_string(x);
  };
  // This is the desirable syntax but it doesn't build
  // fmap(fn)(Foo<int>(42, 7));

  // This builds but it's super ugly
  fmap(fn).operator()<Foo>(Foo<int>(42, 7));
}
```

Based on the response by SkepticalEmpiricist below, I am thinking that type aliases may not be the way to go here and instead I will have to introduce small wrapper classes - unless there is an SFINAE approach that would get this working.

This library is mostly a curiosity and a means for me to explore some more advanced template concepts - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first attempt before we start digging for some SFINAE based trickery to try circumvent [the unavoidable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

> **Alias templates are never deduced by template argument deduction**

We could "deduce" the template arguments for the compiler ourselves like this:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
using Foo = std::tuple<int, T>;

template <template <typename ...> class F, typename T, typename ...Ts>
void foo(F<T, std::string, Ts...> bar) {}

void test() {
  foo(Foo<std::string>());
}
```

So now we have it compiling for your `foo(Foo<std::string>());` call with `Foo` being the *alias template* over `std::tuple` and, more importantly, `foo()` is still specialized only for `Foo<std::string>`.

However, to support usage simultaneously of `foo()` **for both the `std::tuple` *alias template* and the wrapper class** for example, we still don't have it compiling error-free. As in, if we now comment-out the `tuple`-flavor `Foo` and bring back in the wrapper class `Foo` then calling our rewritten `foo()` **will not compile**.

To address the issue, let's give it a try with **SFINAE to the rescue** and replace the last declaration of `foo()` with this code:

```
template <template <typename ...> class F, typename T, typename ...Ts,
          typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<F<T, Ts...>, 
              std::tuple<T, Ts...>>::value >* = nullptr>
void foo(F<T, std::string, Ts...> bar) {}

template <template <typename> class F>
void foo(F<std::string> bar) {}
```

Now you can call `foo()` for instances of both wrapper class of `tuple`s and *alias template* for `tuple`s. You could implement in the same fashion for `std::variant` as well.

Comment: I would prefer that - I am writing a small functor library based loosely on Haskell's functor. I'll add some more context to my original post.

Comment: @Taylor Added an edit to keep the full requirement as I've gathered it from your question to be so far. Let me know where it stands from your point of view.

Comment: Thanks for digging into this. I ended up just going with the wrapper class because I think that the `using` approach may cause more issues down the road. It would be nice if C++ offered something equivalent to Haskell's `newtype` - the simplicity of `using` but it also creates a new type that can be checked with the compiler instead of an alias.

Comment: Marking as the answer because I was not aware that aliases aren't used in type deduction, although I now see why that would be the case.

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
template <typename T> using Foo = std::tuple<int, T>;

template <template <typename> class F> void foo(F<std::string> bar) {}

void test() { foo(Foo<std::string>()); }
```

`Foo<std::string>` is `std::tuple<int, std::string>`.

so `test` is

```
void test() { foo(std::tuple<int, std::string>()); }
```

How do you expect compiler deduce from `tuple` from which alias it come ?

we might have

```
template <typename T> using Bar = std::tuple<int, std::string>;
template <typename T> using Bar2 = std::tuple<some_trait<T>::type, some_trait<T>::type2>;
// ...
```

A possible workaround might be:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
Foo<U> fmap(std::function<U(T)> f, Foo<T> value)
{
    return Foo<U>(std::get<0>(value), f(std::get<1>(value)));   
}
```

With calling syntax:

```
fmap(fn, Foo<int>(42, 7));
```